# How to disable save password pop up on form submit in firefox using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to submit a form without any popup appearing in the browser for save passwords. It is not working in Firefox 59 version.

I am trying to login a form which has two password input fields as below:

```
<input type="password" name="logonKey" maxlength="20" size="8" />
<input type="password" name="password" maxlength="100" size="12" />
```

I tried with adding `autocomplete="off"` (doesn't work) and adding `readonly` and `onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');"` (doesn't work) attribute in the elements. But these are not working in Firefox as it is still showing popup of save password.

Kindly help me out a solution for this as I am stuck with going forward.

Comment: It is my decision as the user, whether I want to save passwords in my browser or not. Stop trying to mess with that. You would be _decreasing_ my security (my stored passwords _not_ being automatically suggested by the browser on what _looks_ like your login page, but is actually a phishing site, only heightens my alertness in this situation.)

Comment: yes you are right. but when the user wants not to cache it . how we can do that ?. i meant like banking sites. But is there is any way to programmatically disable the save password pop up?

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers currently ignore the `autocomplete="off"` tag, as it's now considered a best practice to let the browser remember the password for the user...

More information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#The_autocomplete_attribute_and_login_fields)

> ...in-browser password management is generally seen as a net gain for security. Since users do not have to remember passwords that the browser stores for them, they are able to choose stronger passwords than they would otherwise.
>
> 1. If a site sets autocomplete="off" for a form, and the form includes username and password input fields, then the browser will still offer to remember this login, and if the user agrees, the browser will autofill those fields the next time the user visits the page.
> 2. If a site sets autocomplete="off" for username and password input fields, then the browser will still offer to remember this login, and if the user agrees, the browser will autofill those fields the next time the user visits the page.
>
> This is the behavior in Firefox (since version 38), Google Chrome (since 34), and Internet Explorer (since version 11).
>
> If an author would like to prevent the autofilling of password fields in user management pages where a user can specify a new password for someone other than themself, autocomplete="new-password" should be specified, though support for this has not been implemented in all browsers yet.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type="password" name="logonKey" maxlength="20" size="8" autocomplete="off"/>
            <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="100" size="12" autocomplete="off"/>
```

Add AutoComplete off on your form tag as well.

Comment: Thanks @Geek Code for your quick reply. But i  have tried this still i am getting the save password poup in the firefox browser